# R plot random graph with same structure

Tags: r, random, plot, igraph

I'm creating a random graph in `R` with the `igraph`-library.

```
library(igraph)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(12, 0.25)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(g)
plot(g)
```

This creates the following plot:

[image: random graph]

As you can see, it creates **two different plots** - even given the same nodes and edges. How can I make R plot the same plots, so I can highlight some edges/nodes while having the same order.

The goal is to create a random network with some degree of probability that two nodes are connected by an edge (above example is `p=0.25` for `n=12` nodes). Then this graph is plotted with the nodes on the same spot (even if the node size variies) everytime I plot it.

How do I do this? Note that I'm not limited to `g <- erdos.renyi.game(12, 0.25)` - it just did the job with the random network quite well.

Comment: I might completely miss the mark of your intent, but if you want to have "consistent randomness", you should `set.seed`.

Comment: not quite. I generate the random graph `g` only once. I want this graph plotted the same. The graph `g` does not change structure between plots.

Comment: I looked into the package and realized that very idea of this function is to produce random graphs. Only quick solution that pops in mind is to save this graph to an image file and then plot this image twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As default in igraph `layout= layout_nicely` which recalculated each plot

You can try to specify layout as matrix or as function to get coordinates

> layout
>
> Either a function or a numeric matrix. It specifies how the
>   vertices will be placed on the plot.
>
> If it is a numeric matrix, then the matrix has to have one line for
>   each vertex, specifying its coordinates. The matrix should have at
>   least two columns, for the x and y coordinates, and it can also have
>   third column, this will be the z coordinate for 3D plots and it is
>   ignored for 2D plots.....

For example

```
g <- erdos.renyi.game(12, 0.25)
g$layout <- layout_as_star
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(g)
plot(g)
```

Give you [image]

or `layout_components`[image]

Full list you can find [here](http://igraph.org/r/doc/layout_.html)

## Update

You can also fix position of points by get coordinates of one graph like :

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for( i in 1:4){
  g <- erdos.renyi.game(12, 0.25)
 if( i ==1) coords <- layout_components(g) # if first -- get coordinates
  g$layout <- coords
  plot(g)
}
```

[image]

Comment: This does the trick sometimes. I just have to try several different random generated graphs `g` until it plots the same and then it plots the same plot everytime (like I wanted it).